# join row with similar date

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm having trouble to join this query.
Here is an example of what I did and what I wish the would be (of course the desired result isn't what I get).

- The `14-02-31 02` is actual a `to_char(a_date,'YY-MM-DD hh24')`.

  ```
  --describe are the same
  sql> desc tab1

   Name              Null?    Type
   ----------------- -------- --------------------------------------------------------
   a_date                       DATE
   NAME                       VARCHAR2(20)

  select * from tab1;
  a_date          number
  -----           -------
  14-02-31 03     12
  14-02-31 04     22
  14-02-31 05     32
  14-02-31 06     42

  select * from tab2;
  a_date          number
  -----           -------
  14-02-31 02     21
  14-02-31 03     22
  14-02-31 06     23
  14-02-31 07     24

  select * from tab3;
  a_date          number
  -----           -------
  14-02-31 01     121
  14-02-31 03     222
  14-02-31 05     323
  14-02-31 07     424


  select a_date,t1.number,t2.number,t3.number
  from (select * from tab1) t1,
       (select * from tab2) t2,
       (select * from tab3) t3
  where t1.a_date=t2.a_date or
        t1.a_date=t3.a_date or
        t2.a_date=t3.a_date or
        t1.a_date is null or
        t2.a_date is null
  ```

  desired result:

  ```
  a_date          t1.number     t2.number     t3.number       
  -----           -------         -------         -------
  14-02-31 01                                     121
  14-02-31 02                     21
  14-02-31 03     12              22              222
  14-02-31 04     22
  14-02-31 05     32                              323
  14-02-31 06     42              23
  14-02-31 07                     24              424
  ```

Comment: What exactly is stored in your date column? `14-02-31 01` - Here, what does the 01 following 31 mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a `full outer join`:

```
select coalesce(t1.a_date, t2.a_date, t3.a_date) as a_date, t1.number, t2.number, t3.number
from tab1 t1 full outer join
     tab2 t2
     on t2.a_date = t1.a_date full outer join
     tab3 t3
     on t3.a_date = coalesce(t1.a_date, t2.a_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.a_date,t1.number,t2.number,t3.number
from  tab1 t1 left outer join on t1.a_date=t2.a_date
     tab2 t2 left outer join  on t1.a_date=t3.a_date
     tab3 t3  left outer join  on t2.a_date=t3.a_date
where t1.a_date=t2.a_date or
      t1.a_date=t3.a_date or
      t2.a_date=t3.a_date or
      t1.a_date is null or
      t2.a_date is null
```